# how to create Entity and save it to database?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Im creating a spring boot app. I want to save my testEntity in database. Im following this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/
A table should be created automaticly to save Entity.

However when i try to run it as Spring Booot App im getting follwoing errors:

```
Error creating bean with name 'demo' defined in backend.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [test.EntityRepo]: : No qualifying bean of type [test.EntityRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [test.EntityRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

No qualifying bean of type [test.EntityRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Please explain what am i doing wrong and how to fix?

Below you can find datasource configuration and classes.

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:1521/orcl
spring.datasource.username=HR
spring.datasource.password=orcl


spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

testEntity:

```
package test;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;



@Entity
public class testEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long ID;

private String name;

public testEntity() {}

public testEntity(long iD) {
    ID = iD;
}

public testEntity(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(long iD) {
    ID = iD;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

entityRepository:

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EntityRepo extends CrudRepository<testEntity, Long>{
List<testEntity> findByName(String name);
}
```

JPA configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
class JpaConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {

    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
 }

 @Bean
 public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("test");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory.getObject();
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() { 

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
  }
}
```

class with main:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMapRepositories
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}



@Bean
public void demo(EntityRepo repository){
    repository.save(new testEntity("jack"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("demo")
public void demo(EntityRepo repository){
    repository.save(new testEntity("jack"));
}


@Repository("entityRepo")
public interface EntityRepo extends CrudRepository<testEntity, Long>{
List<testEntity> findByName(String name);
}
```

Comment: still same problem appears

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Autowired
public void demo(EntityRepo repository){
    repository.save(new testEntity("jack"));
}
```

Comment: keep your demo method autowired as i mentioned above and remove the @Repository from your interface. clean your project and run again.

Comment: if not ok you can use my code here : (note: its a gradle but you can convert it to maven) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EVyl90ivXwbHlXZDNwcGg5eHM/view

Comment: still did not work ``No qualifying bean of type [test.EntityRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}``, will check your project and let you know

Comment: check my project. I use crudrepo too. I see that u ar using h2, so you have to comment the mysql db settings and uncomment h2 settings in application.properties files in order to let  spring use the default h2 embedded db. This is because i m using mysql.

Comment: correction:  I use crudrepo too. I see that u ar using Oracle, so you have to adapt your db settings with Oracle settings in application.properties file. This is because i m using mysql.

Comment: yes, i know, i have analyzed your project and did adapted my classes to look like yours, but still same problem appears

Comment: Sorry then, You can share your app via github or google drive.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. JpaConfig class was in default package and no path toit was specified, moving JpaConfig file to package with Aplication fixed the problem